# Load fingerprint image in python array

Tags: python, imread

how to load all student fingerprints in the List
by this method

```
for file in [file for file in os. listdir("database")]:
    fingerprint_database_image = cv2.imread("./database/"+file)
```

It did not load my arry
if I give full path like as then ok

```
fingerprint_database_image = cv2.imread("d:/database/1.tif) it ok
```

but I need all student's fingerprints how do I load all image
please give me an idea

Waiting for your prompt help

Regard's